# Let$ (X; T_{\text{cocountable}})$ be an infinite set, show that it is closed under countable intersections.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification

Also give an example to show that $\mathcal{T}_{\text{cocountable}}$ need not be closed under arbitrary intersections.

I was looking for some feedback on my proof:
$X\setminus\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}$, where $I$ is a countable set, equals to $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\{X\setminus A_{\alpha}\}$. The union of countably many sets is also countable and hence, $T_{\text{cocountable}}$ is closed under countable intersections.

An example of an arbitrary intersection could be $X \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$ and $X\setminus \emptyset = X$, which is infinite.

Comment: That's odd. Henno's edit should have overwritten this suggested edit (and it is in fact the better LaTeX'ing). I've reverted to Henno's edit and fixed a couple more problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with the countable intersections, the equivalent formulation that the closed sets are closed under countable unions is even easier.

As to arbitrary intersections, your examples make no sense (the results are both in the topology?).

Instead consider $X_x = X\setminus \{x\}$ for all $x \in X$, all of which are open. Suppose $X$ is uncountable (or else the topology is discrete and closed under all intersections) and write $X$ as a disjoint union $A \cup B$, which are both uncountable. Then $B$ is not open (why?) and $B = \cap_{x \in A} X_x$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, why can we write X as a disjoint union ?

Comment: @jia this is standard set theory. For any infinite set the cardinality of $X$ and a set with two disjoint copies of $X$ is the same (assuming the axiom of choice, as is usual). This gives a bijection between $X$ and two disjoint copies of $X$, pulling these back gives $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine, but the counterexample is not.

The cocountable topology is in fact the topology generated by the cocountable sets, which turns out to be the cocountable sets *and* the empty set.

As a counterexample, pick $A\subseteq X$ such that $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are both uncountable, and use $A$ as an index to find an intersection of cocountable sets which is in fact uncountable.